# Balanced array index while summing an array from left and right

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, sum, range

**Balance Index Problem:**

**Input:** an array of `n` positive integers

**Output:** an index i such that the sum of elements `V[0]...V[i]` is exactly equal to the sum of `v[i + 1]...V[n-1];` or None if no such index exists. For example:

> ```
> [5,1,2,2] -> output i = 0
>
> [1,1,1,1,1,1] -> output = 2
>
> [2,2,2] -> output = None
> ```

Been stuck on this problem for a while can someone help with the basic logic? Something like this psuedocode. Its ment to be basic and simple. Im just not fully understanding the logic.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
    {
        sum1 = array[i] + sum1
        sum2 = array[j] + sum2
        
        if(sum1 == sum2)
            return i; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your intentions with the code? It seems as if the inner loop is supposed to calculate the `v[i+1]...v[n-1]` part. But why is `sum1` in this loop and where are you initializing `sum2` to 0?

Comment: I dont fully understand the initial problem that is my psuedocode or draft i need help with whats going on.

Comment: So, are you asking for help understanding the problem or solving it? Obviously, the latter requires the former. Btw, this problem has (at least) an easy solution and an efficient one.

Comment: Both understanding and solving or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) and you can do as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstddef>

int balanceIndex(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
   for(std::size_t index = 0; index< vec.size(); ++index)
   {
      int left_sum = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + index + 1, 0);
      int right_sum = std::accumulate(vec.begin() + index + 1, vec.end(), 0);
      if(left_sum == right_sum)
         return index;
   }
   return -1;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> a = {5,1,2,2};
  std::vector<int> b = {1,1,1,1,1,1};
  std::vector<int> c = {2,2,2};

  int answer = balanceIndex(c);  //try for vectors b and c
  (answer != -1) ? std::cout<< answer : std::cout << "None\n";

  return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: Above solution has a time complexity of *O(n^2)*. As @NicoSchertler mentioned in the comment, a *O(n)* solution could be as follows:

```
int balanceIndex(const std::vector<int>& vec)
{
   int right_sum = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);
   int left_sum = 0;
   for(std::size_t index = 0; index< vec.size(); ++index)
   {
      right_sum -= vec[index];
      left_sum  += vec[index];
      if(left_sum == right_sum) return index;
   }
   return -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help im going walk through each step.

Comment: @CoderChick Your welcom: See here for live outputs: https://www.ideone.com/FmApiz

Comment: @CoderChick: This is one of the easy solutions I was referring to in the comments under your question. When you understand it, try to modify it to be efficient. This version has a runtime of O(n^2), whereas the efficient one has O(n).

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yes. This has O(n*n) complexity. Using segment tree range  sum, whould be much faster.

Comment: @JeJo Much simpler, the sums can be calculated incrementally without some complex data structure.

Comment: @NicoSchertler  Also true. Moving slide summation. Updated with that. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check for an odd array sum first, and stop before instead of going through all the array a second time.
This algo is linear O(N).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int balanceIndex(const std::vector<int>& array)
{
    int sum = std::accumulate(array.begin(), array.end(), 0);

    if (sum % 2 == 1)
        return -1;

    int leftSum = 0;
    int halfSum = sum / 2;

    size_t index = 0;    
    while(leftSum < halfSum)
        leftSum += array[index++];

    if (leftSum == halfSum)
        return index-1;

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << balanceIndex({5, 1, 2, 2}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << balanceIndex({1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << balanceIndex({2, 2, 2}) << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And the C-Array approach:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

uint32_t sum(uint32_t arr[], uint32_t n)
{
    uint32_t s = 0;
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s += arr[i];
    }
    return s;
}

int32_t getIdx(uint32_t arr[], uint32_t n)
{
    uint32_t sum_l = 0;
    uint32_t sum_r = sum(arr, n);

    if ((sum_r%2) == 1) {
        return -1; //if the sum is odd, then sum(arr[0...i]) != sum(arr[i+1...n-1])
    }

    for (uint32_t i = 0; (i < n) && (sum_r > sum_l); i++) {
        sum_r -= arr[i];
        sum_l += arr[i];
        if (sum_r == sum_l) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t arr1[] = {5, 1, 2, 2};
    cout << "{5, 1, 2, 2}: sum=" << sum(arr1, 4) << " idx=" << getIdx(arr1, 4) << endl;

    uint32_t arr2[] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    cout << "{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}: sum=" << sum(arr2, 6) << " idx=" << getIdx(arr2, 6) << endl;

    uint32_t arr3[] = {2, 2, 2};
    cout << "{2, 2, 2}: sum=" << sum(arr3, 3) << " idx=" << getIdx(arr3, 3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As for understanding problem: you are searching for such index i, that sum of numbers left of i and right of i are equal, for example:

> V = [1 2 3] -> i=1, as V[0] + V[i=1] = V[i+1=2]

As for how to code your program, I suggest TDD approach, i.e. first write test based on my example; then try to write function that pass this test. Next write more complex test (for instance with numbers that wouldn give you valid i)